# Kernel kb filter ioctl IRP / variable declaration error

Tags: c++, c, kernel, driver, wdk

The below code is the (modified) `KbFilter_ServiceCallback` routine from the WDK ***kbfiltr.c*** sample.
As it is, it builds fine but when I uncomment `IRP *irp;`, it causes an error:

> 1>errors in directory c:\winddk\kbfiltr\sys
>   1>c:\winddk\kbfiltr\sys\kbfiltr.c(827) : error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
>   1>link : error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'c:\winddk\kbfiltr\sys\objchk_wxp_x86\i386\kbfiltr.obj'

which isn't very helpful to me. I've read that in a block declarations need to be before any statements, which I'm sure I've done, so I'm really confused about that.

```
    VOID
KbFilter_ServiceCallback(
    IN PDEVICE_OBJECT  DeviceObject,
    IN PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA InputDataStart,
    IN PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA InputDataEnd,
    IN OUT PULONG InputDataConsumed
    )
{
    KEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA *kbDat;//Apparently declarations need to be before any statements
    ULONG consumed;
    //IRP *irp;

    PDEVICE_EXTENSION   devExt;
    WDFDEVICE   hDevice;
    hDevice = WdfWdmDeviceGetWdfDeviceHandle(DeviceObject);
    devExt = FilterGetData(hDevice);    

    kbDat = kbDat = InputDataStart;

    while (kbDat < InputDataEnd)
    {
       consumed = 0;

       if (kbDat->MakeCode == 0x01) {//Esc
           if((kbDat->Flags & KEY_MAKE) == KEY_MAKE){
             //SEND IRP ...IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest(IOCTL_KEYBOARD_SET_INDICATORS,...
           }
        }
        else{
            kbDat++;
             continue;
        }

        (*(PSERVICE_CALLBACK_ROUTINE)(ULONG_PTR) 
    devExt->UpperConnectData.ClassService)(
            devExt->UpperConnectData.ClassDeviceObject,
            kbDat,
            kbDat+1,
            &consumed);
        kbDat++;
    }

    *InputDataConsumed = (InputDataEnd-InputDataStart);


    (*(PSERVICE_CALLBACK_ROUTINE)(ULONG_PTR) devExt->UpperConnectData.ClassService)(
        devExt->UpperConnectData.ClassDeviceObject,
        InputDataStart,
        InputDataEnd,
        InputDataConsumed);
}
```

While I'm here, I also need help filling in
 `//SEND IRP ...IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest(IOCTL_KEYBOARD_SET_INDICATORS,...`. 
I want to send down an **ioctl** **irp** to get the status of the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> light and toggle it when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed. Somewhere ([here](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/32092-toggle-led-lights/)) it was done with `DeviceIoControl` but that requires **windows.h** which when included in **kbfiltr.c** causes a lot of other errors. So I'm wanting to use

`irp = IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest(IOCTL_KEYBOARD_SET_INDICATORS,...
IoCallDriver( ..., irp );`
but I haven't managed to get this working. I've been going in circles with this the past few days so I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: `warning treated as error` - this is shown after some warning. Where is the warning itself?

Comment: This was the warning:

1>warnings in directory c:\winddk\kbfiltr\sys
1>c:\winddk\kbfiltr\sys\kbfiltr.c(827) : warning C4101: 'irp' : unreferenced local variable

Comment: So it's warning because the declared variable isn't used? Why does that turn into an error?

Comment: There is compiler switch "Treat warnings as errors". Remove unused variable or change compilation options.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Does anyone know how to construct the IRP?  I still haven't got it figured out, especially what the second (device) argument would be. I've tried deviceobject->next but no luck.

Comment: Windows drivers questions is better to ask on osronline.